# looping error in java

Tags: java, mysql, loops, netbeans

When I run this code, the code shows errors. Please help me to fix this problem.
Here is my Java code:

```
public void kirim(){
    try{
    koneksi();
    String data ="select count(Number) from pbk";
    ResultSet rs1 = cn.executeQuery(data);
    while (rs1.next()){
        rs1.getString(1);
    }
    int banyakData=Integer.parseInt(rs1.getString(1));

    for (int i=0; i<=banyakData ;i++){
    String sqi = "select Number from pbk";
    ResultSet rs = cn.executeQuery(sqi);
    while(rs.next()){
        rs.getString(sqi);
    }          
    String sql="insert into outbox (DestinationNumber, TextDecoded, CreatorID) values ("
    + "'"+sqi +"',"
    + "'" + jTextArea1.getText()+ "',"
    + "'1'"
    + ")";
    cn.executeUpdate(sql);

    } JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Pesan terkirim");
    }catch (Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Pesan gagal terkirim");
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Here is stack trace output:

```
After end of result set
```

Comment: Would have appreciated if you would have provided the stack trace.

Comment: I suspect that the error is raised from: `rs.getString(sqi);` since `sqi` is not a valid argument... By the way - you get downvoted since you didn't provide the full stacktrace and you don't show us which line triggers the error (it's in the stacktrace as well).

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to

```
ResultSet rs1 = cn.executeQuery(data);
int banyakData;
    while (rs1.next()){
       banyakData= rs1.getInt(1);
    }
```

and remove

```
  int banyakData=Integer.parseInt(rs1.getString(1));
```

With you approach you have already iterated through the resultset and after the completition of the while loop you are again fetching from resultset giving you the error.

And also simply doing `rs.getString(sqi);` and `rs1.getString(1);` in a while loop doesnt make any sense if you dint put the result in any variable btw `sqi` is not a valid parameter.

Comment: I think you meant `rs1.getInt(1)`

Comment: thanks bro. but after i change that i found new errors. here is my errors 'Column 'select Number from pbk' not found.'

Comment: in my java code haven't show error, but when I compile this, out message 'column select  Number from pbk not found''